# Show/hide an element onclick

Tags: javascript

I am just making a simple practice script that is supposed to show a paragraph when you click on an h1 heading.  For some reason, it does not work locally, but I have it working fine in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/q5PF3/

HTML:

```
 <h1 id="clicker">Click me</h1>
 <p id="hidden">Ta daaaa!</p>
```

CSS:

```
#hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var click = document.getElementById("clicker");
var xtra = document.getElementById("hidden");
click.onclick = function() {
if(xtra.style.display == "none") {
    xtra.style.display = "inline";
}
else{
    xtra.style.display = 'none';
}
};
```

Comment: And what kind of help you're expecting then? Take your code and see the differences

Comment: jsfiddle wraps the javascript in a function, an assigns it to `window.onload`. Are you doing the same locally?

Comment: That fixed it.  Thanks!  Also, there was something funny going on with my formatting when I posted this.  I was doing the 4 space indent, but it didn't work.

Comment: @NickD similarly, put your JS at the BOTTOM of your HTML file so it loads after everything else.